# Is it possible to create an ipa file for the App Store with developer account?

Tags: ios, code-signing, tvos

I am working on a tvOS app. I need to create an ipa file. The client has provided a distribution certificate and a provisional profile for the app. But, the client has not provided any Apple Developer account details. Is it possible to create a valid ipa file for App Store?

Comment: No, you can't create/upload without Developer Account Details.

Comment: No you can't but you can ask to client to send invite you and then you can access his account from your current account

Comment: Thanks for clear my confusion.

Answer (score 0):

You will not be able to be able to create a valid ipa without being part of their team on the Members Centre.

However, it should be relatively straightforward for them to re-sign the IPA, instructions can be found here:

[How to Re-Sign an iOS App from an External Developer](http://dev.mlsdigital.net/posts/how-to-resign-an-ios-app-from-external-developers/)

This means you can just sign the ipa with your regular developers profile.

It may be worth noting that they can add you to their team on the Developer Centre without adding you to their team on iTunes connect as they are two separate services. This means you can provide them with a valid, signed build which they could then upload to iTunes Connect themselves.